# How to get tag name for given word in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have some html code like this:

```
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text"><a href="something.com">sometext for example</a></div>
```

I'm searching sometext word using jsoup and I want it's tag name. For above example it will be `a href`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS selector:

```
*:containsOwn(sometext)
```

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~1FKtzLpHQFii4u8FFyUuh3GgdPI

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<div class=\"post-text\" itemprop=\"text\"><a href=\"something.com\">sometext for example</a></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elts = doc.select("*:containsOwn(sometext)");

for(Element e : elts) {
   System.out.println(e.outerHtml());
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<a href="something.com">sometext for example</a>
```

#### SEE ALSO

- `:matchesOwn(regex)` - If you want to find element with more elaborate text.
- [Jsoup CSS selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) - The complete reference on CSS selectors supported by Jsoup